# How to insert some horizontal space between two divs inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a removable div element that will consist of two other divs: the text div and the remove div.

I am setting `display: inline-block` on `removable_item_container` to adjust the width of the container to the div contents.

But how can I insert some white space (let's say 20% of the container width) between `removable_item_text` and `removable_item_remove` elements and keep the first element aligned to the left of the container div and the other one to the right?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700|Montserrat:300" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            }
            .removable_item_container {
                display: inline-block;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 0.1px;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .removable_item_container:hover {
                color: blue;
                cursor: grab;
            }
            .removable_item_text {
                float: left;
            }
            .removable_item_remove {
                float: right;
            }
            .removable_item_remove:hover {
                color: red;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="removable_item_container">
            <div class="removable_item_text">Removable item</div>
            <div class="removable_item_remove">x</div>
        </div>
    
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If a fixed space is ok for you, just add `margin-left:20px` for `.removable_item_remove`.

Comment: Stick some `margin` on either a or b

Comment: @Victor, @David: I have tried your suggestions, but then the `removable_item_remove` gets moved to the next line of the enclosing div.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the question, so this is a comment, not an answer, but setting ``width:40%`` on each of the items will leave 20% of the width between them.

Comment: you can use a *pseudo element* with `width: 20%` and use a flexbox container and `order` property to put it in between... see https://jsfiddle.net/pynx2s5w/ let me know if this is the requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-left:20px` to add a fixed space width, and both elements will be shown on the same line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700|Montserrat:300" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            }
            .removable_item_container {
                display: inline-block;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 0.1px;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .removable_item_container:hover {
                color: blue;
                cursor: grab;
            }
            .removable_item_text {
                float: left;
            }
            .removable_item_remove {
                float: right;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }
            .removable_item_remove:hover {
                color: red;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="removable_item_container">
            <div class="removable_item_text">Removable item</div>
            <div class="removable_item_remove">x</div>
        </div>
    
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work, but as per my question I would like to use relative, not fixed width for the white space. If I replace `20px` with `10%` for example, the second element will be moved to next line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a **responsive** way of doing this you could use flexbox.

https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

1. Set `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` on `.removable_item_container`
2. Give `.removable_item_text` a `flex-basis` of lets say `70%` (as example)
3. Give `.removable_item_remove` a `flex-basis`of lets say `10%`
4. I also added `text-align: right;` to your right element.
5. You can then give your desired with to `.removable_item_container` (200px in my example)

This will make the **remaining** space be 20% of the total width of your element.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.removable_item_container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.removable_item_container:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: grab;
}

.removable_item_text {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.removable_item_remove {
text-align: right;
 flex-basis: 10%;
  float: right;
}

.removable_item_remove:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700|Montserrat:300" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="removable_item_container">
    <div class="removable_item_text">Removable item</div>
    <div class="removable_item_remove">x</div>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, I don't want the width of the div to be fixed (200px in your example), I need it to adapt to the text inside it. In your example, if I make the the text inside the div much longer, it will overflow the div border.

Comment: @barciewicz Well the 200px was solely for demonstration purposes, ofc you can make it as big as you want